# Program works in cmd, immediately exits with status 127 in cygwin, no output in emacs shell

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin, mingw, command-prompt

I've got the following program, which I'm compiling using MinGW:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "aoeu" << endl;
    string str;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this program in the Windows command prompt, I get the following output as expected:

```
C:\p\conscell>conscell.exe
aoeu
```

However, when I run it in Cygwin, I get the following output (or lack thereof):

```
$ ./conscell.exe
$ echo $?
127
```

As you can see, the exit code is 127, indicating that the file or a library dependency could not be found.  Additionally, when I run the program in `M-x shell` in emacs (which runs `C:/Program Files/Emacs/libexec/emacs/25.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdproxy.exe`) there is no output.

When I delete the `string str;` line, changing the program to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "aoeu" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then Cygwin and Emacs CAN find the file, as witnessed by the Cygwin output:

```
$ ./conscell.exe
aoeu
```

This would appear to indicate that using an `std::string` in the program causes it to depend on some files that cmd can find, but Cygwin and cmdproxy.exe cannot.  Any help on figuring out what files those are would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your executable with dependency walker or similar utilities to figure out on which libraries it depends on. And then put them into the same folder as executable so they can be found regardless of current environment. See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Alternatively you can link them statically.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the answer (see comments on the other answer).  I'll finish testing everything tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  To be precise I got the names of all the DLLs that were loaded by modifying [this code](http://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?t=563414) and starting the exe paused using [cheat engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/) although any debugger should work.  Then for each loaded DLL I ran `where [dll]` in a terminal to find out where it was coming from.  They were all from system32 except for `libstdc++-6.dll` which was from mingw AND from gtksharp which appeared before mingw in PATH.  In my case I didn't need gtksharp so I uninstalled it and now everything works.

Comment: Of course, if I'm ever going to give these programs to people, I should either compile with `-static-libc++` or package the DLL anyway...

Answer (score 1):

MinGW compile with GCC but for Windows environment so it sometimes uses windows libs and compiles for the windows architecture.
Cygwin is a lightweight Unix environment.

If I'm not mistaken cygwin includes MinGW or GCC.
If you want to run your program on Windows compile with standalone minGW
If you want it to run on Unix work on Unix OS.
If you want for both you will have to compile twice I think. Use a makefile that compile with both compilers.

Comment: I can run plenty of other EXEs using Cygwin.  My workflow includes testing applications inside emacs shell, so I'd like to be able to compile and run there.

Comment: So other programs you compiled works on CMD and cygwin and emacs but this one particularly doesn't?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.  I don't know if I should say this, but before I reinstalled windows I could compile and run programs using `std::string` all within emacs shell, and now I cannot.  I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Maybe the architecture, do you compile in 32 or 64?

Comment: Compiling 32-bit, running on 64-bit.

Comment: Try this option -static-libstdc++ as VTT said it could fix the problem by not letting dynamic linking appear

Comment: Thanks @HangrY, that option fixes it.

Comment: You should validate @VTT answer :)

Comment: I'm workin' on it.  I got the names of all the DLL files loaded by the exe with and without -static-libstdc++, now I just need to try moving them into a directory where the system searches for DLLs.

Comment: I'll finish tomorrow :V